# Update context of FormView only in certain condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a code in my `FormView` in Django:

```py
class SearchView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = "dic_records/search_form.html"
    form_class = KokyakuForm
    success_url = 'search'
    fetched_data = []

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        kokyaku_instance = FetchKokyaku(form.cleaned_data['name_search'])
        err_check = kokyaku_instance.connect()
        kokyaku_instance.get_data()
        if err_check is False:
            messages.error(self.request, "データを出力できませんでした")
            return super(SearchView, self).form_valid(form)
        
        kokyaku_list = list(kokyaku_instance.get_data())
        if len(kokyaku_list) == 0:
            messages.error(self.request, "検索のデータを見つけられませんでした")
            return super(SearchView, self).form_valid(form)
        self.fetched_data = kokyaku_list
        return super(SearchView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Use this to add extra context."""
        context = super(SearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['list'] = self.fetched_data
        return context
```

And I would like to provide to template a list of values `kokyaku_list` from `context` variable, but only if my `form` is valid and data are fetched from `kokyaku_instance.get_data()`.

The code above wont pass values

Comment: If your form is valid, you're redirecting users to the success url. In that case what is the meaning of passing additional context in the current view?